# In Eclipse i have deleted the project contents on the disk.how can i restore it

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse i have deleted the project contents on the disk.I search every where but i cant get it.It is not in workspace also.It is very important  project any way to get it back please help me out

Comment: Check it out of the repository again.

Comment: You mean you did the thing that says "(Cannot be undone)" and want to know if it can be undone? There is a warning there for a reason. Your only shot is file recovery at the OS level, and pray those sectors haven't been overwritten by some other file.

Comment: Yes i clicked that "cannot be undone check box. Where can i find my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your operating system, but there are several recovery-tools available outthere, heres a video from youtube showing you how to do this "easy"

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vki3_zJZ8gY

Comment: thanks man i'll search in that recovery tools. Any other was is there to recover it

Comment: i cant restored that project that i've deleted do u have any another idea

Comment: Exactly like @Adrian Mouat said, check it out from your repository again.

Comment: where is the repository again can u help it

Comment: It is impossible to restore it without some effort, like in the link i showed you.

Comment: i've try that recovery soft i cant get that deleted files. It is not showing that deleted files

Comment: You might as well give up then, and start using some sort of version control system in the future.

Comment: every hard work i've done for that project is gone ya.V cant get it back ya.